# how debug the vc++ Dll

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, visual-c++, dll

How to debug the  vc++ Dll in visual studio 08.I also include breckpoint and pass the exe but still not succeed.The error message that

**The breakpoint will not currently be hit.No symbols have been
    loaded for this document.**

Comment: What dll are you trying to debug?

Comment: How are you loading the DLL? Are you loading it dynamically with `LoadLibrary()`, or are you linking against an import lib? The devil is in the details...

Comment: Do a full build, and make sure the loaded DLL and PDB are up to date.

Comment: actually the exe is build in visual studia 6.0 and the  new version of the dll is made in visual studio 8

Comment: Execute "Rebuild All" in both projects (dll, exe). Start debugging. In the Output window see Dll loading report: it prints when Dll is loaded, and whether debugging symbols are loaded/not found. Post more details about debugging process.

Comment: @AlexFarber I have to build new dll(vs8) that should be compatible with old exe(vs6).So I can't rebuild the exe

Answer (score 1):

**The breakpoint will not currently be hit.No symbols have been loaded for this document.**

You get this message when the `.pdb` file was not found or is not compatible with your dll version.

Try doing the following:

1) Check if the `.pdb` file exists in the same location as the `.dll` or in Visual Studio's pdb file directory.

2) If it exists, try manually loading it - right click on the module and select load symbols from.

3) If you get an error saying the pdb is not compatible with your `dll`... well... it means just that. You can either recompile or try to find the compatible version.

Comment: I checked but .pdb file is not exists.

Comment: If the file you're trying to debug doesn't have any debug information... you can't debug it. If you can't do a rebuild with debug information on that module, there's no way to debug it. If it was built with debug information, try to find the pdb and put it in the same directory as your binary. You can check if the module was built with or without debug information in the modules tab (while in debug mode) of visual studio.

Comment: there is the file with extantion .pdd(program debug database).Is it same as with .pdb file

Comment: I've never heard of a .pdd extension. Did you check whether the module was built with or without debug information?